Create list of important definitions and theorems
In the same way I can list all theorems and/or definitions that are defined in the text, I want to be able to mark a subset of them that are most important, and display a list of them.
Is there a way to achieve this without defining a custom important_thm theorem environment (for example)?
Is it possible to filter the list of theorems by those that have a description? (Like [Important theorem] below)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\begin{document}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\listoftheorems

\begin{thm}
    Don't include this theorem in the list of theorems 
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[Important theorem]
    Include this one
\end{thm}
\end{document}


Thankyou in advance!

How many truly important definitions and theorems does your document feature? If the number is reasonable, say, five or less, wouldn’t it be easier to enter this list by hand — the more so as this short list is (hopefully!) not going to change from one edit to another?

You can do this with the seq key of keytheorems (disclaimer, I wrote the package).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keytheorems}

\newkeytheorem{thm}[name=Theorem]

\begin{document}

\listofkeytheorems[seq=important]

\begin{thm}
    Don't include this theorem in the list of theorems 
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[
  note=Important theorem,
  seq=important]
    Include this one
\end{thm}

\end{document}


